# CSSだけでdisplay: noneをかけた要素の大きさを保持したい

Tags: html, css

掲題の通りHTMLを一切編集せず、JSも使わずdisplay: noneがされた要素の部分だけ大きさを保持しておきたいです。

min-width-heightで可能かと思いましたがやぱり消えてしまいました。
どうすればうまくいくでしょうか。

```
div {
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

端的に言えば、**不可能**だと思います。

なぜならば、 `display` プロパティに none を指定した場合、**ボックスは生成されない**からです。また、 `offsetWidth`, `offsetHeight` 属性などは、要素に関連付けられた CSS レイアウトボックスがない場合に、 0 を返します<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-htmlelement-offsetwidth)</sup>。

> ### 9.2.4 The 'display' property<sup>[[2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#propdef-display)</sup>
>
> This value causes an element to not appear in the formatting structure (i.e., in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no effect on layout). Descendant elements do not generate any boxes either; the element and its content are removed from the formatting structure entirely. This behavior cannot be overridden by setting the `display` property on the descendants.
>
> Please note that a display of 'none' does not create an invisible box; it creates no box at all. CSS includes mechanisms that enable an element to generate boxes in the formatting structure that affect formatting but are not visible themselves. Please consult the section on visibility for details.

要素によって生成されたボックスを不可視にした上で、レイアウトに影響を与えるためには、 `visibility` プロパティを用いることが出来ます。

> ### 11.2 Visibility: the 'visibility' property<sup>[[3]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#propdef-visibility)</sup>
>
> The `visibility` property specifies whether the boxes generated by an element are rendered. Invisible boxes still affect layout (set the `display` property to 'none' to suppress box generation altogether). Values have the following meanings:
>
> - **hidden**
>     The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.

```css
div {
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

参考:

1. [CSSOM View Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/)
2. [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 2 (CSS 2.2) Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/)

Answer (score 3):

`display: none` では不可能です。CSSのボックスツリーから外れるため、他のプロパティもいっさい効力がなくなります。親のボックスで大きさを確保するしかありません。

`visibility: hidden` や `opacity: 0` で消すのはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

他の方もご指摘のように、display:noneで要素の保持はできません。
ご希望にそうなら、visibility:hidden です。
両方とも要素を非表示にできますが、その違いは「非表示にする」か「要素自体をなくす」かの違いです。
display:noneは要素自体をなくすので、大きさを保持すると言うことはできません。
しかし、DOMからは消えないのでHTMLコード上では存在していることになります。